# Power BI - MoM % is showing total of 0% when I would like it to show the most recent months MoM %

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am attempting to create a card within Power BI that calculates a MoM change in a value. I want it to show the most recent month to date vs the previous month of the data. However, it looks like it is calculating the total. The measure I have looks like it would be calculating this correctly, but it is not being displayed in the card correctly.

The measure:

```
TTL BELOW FLR MoM% = 
IF(
    ISFILTERED('IA_TCALENDAR_DATES'[CALENDAR_D]),
    ERROR("Time intelligence quick measures can only be grouped or filtered by the Power BI-provided date hierarchy or primary date column."),
        VAR __CURR_MONTH =
        CALCULATE(
            [TTL BELOW FLR],
            DATEADD('IA_TCALENDAR_DATES'[CALENDAR_D], 0, MONTH)
        )
    VAR __PREV_MONTH =
        CALCULATE(
            [TTL BELOW FLR],
            DATEADD('IA_TCALENDAR_DATES'[CALENDAR_D], -1, MONTH)
        )
    RETURN
        DIVIDE(__CURR_MONTH - __PREV_MONTH, __PREV_MONTH)
)
```

[Calc is 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FjxJ.jpg)

I am expecting it to show the - 83% (in the attached picture) as the most recent month in the dashboard is filtered to February 2023.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the measure that I used to output the most recent month's vs previous month's value:

```
MoM % = var PREV = IF(MONTH(MAX(FACT_SALES[DATE])) = 1,CALCULATE([VALUE/ TOTAL VALUE],CALENDARTABLE[YEAR] = (YEAR(MAX(FACT_SALES[DATE])) - 1), CALENDARTABLE[MONTH] = 12), CALCULATE([VALUE/ TOTAL VALUE],CALENDARTABLE[YEAR] = YEAR(MAX(FACT_SALES[DATE])), CALENDARTABLE[MONTH] = (MONTH(MAX(FACT_SALES[DATE]))-1))) var Present = CALCULATE([VALUE/ TOTAL VALUE],CALENDARTABLE[YEAR] = YEAR(MAX(FACT_SALES[DATE])),CALENDARTABLE[MONTH] = MONTH(MAX(FACT_SALES[DATE]))) return (Present - Prev)
```

Answer (score 0):

The card (and Total row) shows the MOM% without an applied evaluation context except for page/report level filters.

To get a different result, either constrain your DAX to use the maximum reported date (or today) as an upper bound, or set a relative date filter on your visualization.